# AnkhSvn - source control provider not available in plug-in selection

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

I tried to reinstall it several times but I don't have AnkhSVN source control plugin available in combo-box chooser:

[image]

AnkhSVN extension is correctly installed and visibled in "Extensions and Updates" screen:

[image]

Windows 8.1, 64-bit, Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 3

Installed plugins (based on About dialog):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Installed Version: Professional

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02801
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0444002-02801
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02801
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0444002-02801
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02801
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06177-004-0444002-02801
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

MySQL for Visual Studio   1.2.3
Data design and management tools for MySQL.  Copyright © 2007-2014 Oracle, Inc.

NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50313.46
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.30919.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Visual Assist   
For more information about Visual Assist, see the Whole Tomato Software website at http://www.WholeTomato.com. Copyright (c) 1997-2014 Whole Tomato Software, Inc.

Xoreax IncrediBuild   5.0 (build 1496)
Xoreax IncrediBuild 5.0 (build 1496)

Qt Add-in 1.2.3
This is Visual Studio Add-in component for Qt. For more information about Qt, see 
http://qt.digia.com
Copyright (C) 2012 Digia Plc and/or its subsidiary(-ies)
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Got exactly the same issue, with exactly the same setup.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It seems to some bug in Visual Studio, because I have the same problem with few more plugins (but not all of them). And on another computer all plugins works ok.

Comment: I reinstalled Visual Studio, and was at least able to get VisualSVN installed (which also wouldn't install before). AnkhSVN still wouldn't install though.